# Exposing constexpr specialized template functions in a library

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++

I have a class with template functions. One of them is a *constexpr* function. I want to compile this class as library and use specialized template functions from other clients.
Example:

```
//in myclass.h
struct myclass{
template<typename Entity>
static constexpr const char* myfnc1();

template<typename Entity>
static std::string myfnc2();
};

//in myclass.cpp
template<> const char* myclass::myfnc1<AnotherClass>() {return "str";}
template<> std::string myclass::myfnc2<AnotherClass2>() {return "str2"; }

template const char* myclass::myfnc1<AnotherClass>();
template std::string myclass::myfnc2<AnotherClass2>();
```

When I try to use `myfnc1<AnotherClass>` at another library it says it is not defined, but I can use `myfnc2<AnotherClass2>`. When I check the libmyclass.so with `nm` I can see that myfnc2 template created with AnotherClass2 but myfnc1 is not. I understand that is the reason, but wonder is there anyway to make the code work it is?

I am using g++ version 4.4.2.

Comment: What is the sense of having a constexpr function which is only visible in a cpp file and exposed as a library function? It can't be evaluated at compile time as its definition is invisible.

Comment: @Klaus Well, those templates used in the same library, now they need to be used outside of library. I can not move them to header file because the actual implementation of those functions uses headers with different #define directives. I do not want to use those headers like that everywhere. I am not allowed to change constexprness of functions. Examples are just to clarify the question, I know it hides the motivation.

Comment: g++ version 4.4.2 ? isn't that like _very old_ ?

Comment: Indeed it is, but I can not change it. Maybe it is because of the compiler version as @Klaus mentioned. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I change:

```
template std::string myclass::myfnc2<AnotherClass2>() {return "str2"; }
```

to

```
template<> std::string myclass::myfnc2<AnotherClass2>() {return "str2"; }
```

I can compile. Typo?

```
> g++ -fPIC -shared x.cpp -O3 -o x.so
> nm x.so | c++filt | grep fnc
```

results to:

```
0000000000000680 T char const* myclass::myfnc1<AnotherClass>()
0000000000000690 T std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > myclass::myfnc2<AnotherClass2>()
```

I don't know if you was really able to compile with the failure in the code. But I can compile it with the change and get the results as expected. But I am using a `g++ (GCC) 8.2.1`.

Comment: You are correct, there was a typo, I am really sorry for that. But that was not the issue, It compiles without an error but when I tried to use the function it complains. It is strange that you can see the function though, I will also try it with newer compiler.

Comment: @Revolver: If some answer is helpful, you should think about an upvote. If it helps you to resolve your problem, you should accept an answer. Thats how we pay for the effort of the people who help us ;)

Comment: after I check with the newer compiler I will do that:)